# Grails 3, how to run projects which had an older grails version

Tags: grails

[here](https://github.com/vahidhedayati/testwebsocket-grails3) is a grails project, but if you have grails 3.3 installed, and try to run it with "grails run-app" it throws the error:

```
| Error Error initializing classpath: Unsupported method: GrailsClasspath.getError().
The version of Gradle you connect to does not support that method.
```

Any ideas how to run it?  Do I have to find, install, then change my paths to point to the old version, or is there some other way using gradle?

I see there is something called gradlew.bat, but looking through the [grails docs](http://docs.grails.org/latest/guide/single.html), it doesnt say how to use it.  is gradlew.bat like the grails command line, and, if so, where is it documented on how to use it?

Comment: Yep... need to have and use the correct version of Grails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Any ideas how to run it?

```
./gradlew bootRun
```

> Do I have to find, install, then change my paths to point to the old
>   version, or is there some other way using gradle?

No, you don't have to install Gradle and you don't have to do anything with your PATH.  That is the point of the wrapper (gradlew).